# How to generate custom purchase order numbering in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have multiple suppliers from which I purchase items. I want to automatically generate my internal purchase order codes in Microsoft SQL Server for each supplier, like this:

Supplier A:

- 2023_A_001
- 2023_A_002

Supplier B:

- 2023_B_001
- 2023_B_002

(first current year, then the supplier's unique code and then number for that supplier for that year).

How do I accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: So how would you handle two suppliers  Acme an Apex?

Comment: A, B is simplified, in reality each supplier has a 3 letter code. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: if you have a supplier table, you can have a field that controls the current serie number, which you retrieve and increment every time new purchase order is created, by concating current year, supplier code and this supplier counter, you will get a purchase order code

Comment: Yes, I understand this concept, but how to do it technically? With a trigger?

Answer (score 0):

A tracking table can be used to assign serial numbers with additional key attributes. Below is an example table and proc similar to ones I've used in the past for this requirement. This version returns the formatted value as a result set but an output parameter could be used instead.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PurchaseOrderSerial(
      PurchaseYear smallint NOT NULL
    , SupplierCode varchar(10) NOT NULL
    , Seq smallint NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT PK_PurchaseOrderSerial PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PurchaseYear, Seq)
);
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.usp_GetNextPurchaseOrderSerial
      @PurchaseYear smallint
    , @SupplierCode varchar(10)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
DECLARE @Seq smallint;

BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRAN; --use transaction to avoid race condition on insert of new year/supplier

    UPDATE dbo.PurchaseOrderSerial
    SET @Seq = Seq += 1
    WHERE
        PurchaseYear = @PurchaseYear
        AND SupplierCode = @SupplierCode;

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Seq = 1;
        INSERT INTO dbo.PurchaseOrderSerial(PurchaseYear, SupplierCode, Seq)
        VALUES (@PurchaseYear, @SupplierCode, @Seq)
    END;

    IF @Seq > 999 THROW 50000, 'Serial number overflow', 1;

    COMMIT;

    SELECT CONCAT(CAST(@PurchaseYear AS char(4)), '_', @SupplierCode, '_', RIGHT('00' + CAST(@Seq AS varchar(10)), 3)) AS PurchaseOrderNumber;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;
    THROW;

END CATCH;
GO

--example execution
EXEC dbo.usp_GetNextPurchaseOrderSerial
      @PurchaseYear = 2023
    , @SupplierCode = 'B';
GO
```